# Change Index Mode programmatically

Tags: magento2, collection, indexing, programmatically

i am looking for a way to change the mode of Magento 2 Indexer.

The way it was done in Mage 1 :

```
$pCollection = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection();

        foreach ($pCollection as $process) {
            $process->setMode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_MANUAL)->save();
            //$process->setMode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME)->save();
        }
```

Is this even possible in Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 2):

Now in Magento 2 we have two modes: "on save" and "on schedule".

See example code that switch  fulltext indexer to on save mode.

```
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry */
    $indexerRegistry = \Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getObjectManager()
        ->get(\Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry::class);
    $indexerRegistry->get(Fulltext::INDEXER_ID)->setScheduled(false);
```

Comment: i want to change the mode of all indexers to "on schedule" can u give me that part ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code based on : `Magento\Indexer\Controller\Adminhtml\Indexer\MassChangelog`

```
foreach ($indexerIds as $indexerId) {
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerInterface $model */
    $model = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry')->get($indexerId);
    $model->setScheduled(true);
}
```

IndexerIds can be retrieve on the code or by Magento command :

```
design_config_grid                       Design Config Grid
customer_grid                            Customer Grid
catalog_category_product                 Category Products
catalog_product_category                 Product Categories
catalog_product_price                    Product Price
catalog_product_attribute                Product EAV
catalogrule_rule                         Catalog Rule Product
catalogrule_product                      Catalog Product Rule
cataloginventory_stock                   Stock
catalogsearch_fulltext                   Catalog Search
targetrule_product_rule                  Product/Target Rule
targetrule_rule_product                  Target Rule/Product
salesrule_rule                           Sales Rule
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the mode via command line

```
php bin/magento indexer:set-mode {realtime|schedule} [indexer-name]
```

“realtime” is equal to  **“Update on Save”** and “schedule” is equal to **“Update by Schedule”**.